# How does AWS Cognito redirect user to a http endpoint by passing his auth token to say he is authenticate user?

Tags: authentication, http-redirect, amazon-cognito

Is it possible that AWS Cognito redirects user to a http endpoint with user's access token if the user is authenticate user with Cognito? I need to implement this authorization flow in react web application. Basic idea is that user gives his credentials such as user's email address and password, then Cognito takes them to check if he is authenticate user or not. If he is, it should redirect user by passing the token to callback URL (in my case this is an http endpoint). After then the URL gets the token, it gives him access as final step.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. But you need to make sure your HTTP endpoint is able to redirect back to an UI page (Or React route) or render HTML after accessing the token retrieved in parameters.

Note: Simply having a HTTP backend URL won't work since the authentication flow requires to redirect the user to the application.

Comment: Would you have more information about how to implemente that precisely please?